# How to count weeks for more than 1 years in Excel? WeekNum in excel resets after every year

Tags: excel, week-number

How to count weeks for more than 1 years in Excel? WeekNum in excel resets after every year.

```
'S# Date                           WeekNum
357 Saturday, December 23, 2017     51
358 Sunday, December 24, 2017       52
359 Monday, December 25, 2017       52
360 Tuesday, December 26, 2017      52
361 Wednesday, December 27, 2017    52
362 Thursday, December 28, 2017     52
363 Friday, December 29, 2017       52
364 Saturday, December 30, 2017     52
365 Sunday, December 31, 2017       53
366 Monday, January 1, 2018         1
```

against row # 366 , in the last column i need week 53 to continue and than next week to 54 and so on as the date goes till 2020. Any method in Excel, R or Python

Answer (score 0):

imho, NoOfWeek = DayDifference/7 should work.

`=CEILING.MATH(Date2-Date1)/7)` or `=FLOOR.MATH(Date2-Date1)/7)`

Does this work on your excel version?

Answer (score 0):

In excel you can use the ROUNDUP function

=ROUNDUP((A1-$A$1+1)/7,0)

A1 is the first cell for date column

-$A$1+1 is the date from where onward firstWeekNum start

Answer (score 0):

If your sheet is always set this way, with S. No. 1 corresponding to 1st Jan, then you can just use the serial numbers to calculate the week:

```
=CEILING.MATH(<CELL-REF>/7)
```